# Encrypt or obfuscate parameter in .net and decrypt in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the MVCReportViewer in my application to show some invoices to my users.  By default MVCReportViewer embeds the report using an iframe.  Unfortunately this allows the user to view the source and change the customer ID to see anyone elses invoices.  Which is a problem.

I was wondering if there is a way I can encrypt or obfuscate the parameter in .net before I send it to SQL, then decrypt or restore it there in the query.

As a note the database data is created by a 3rd party program, so I can unfortunately not edit that and just use some other method to get the customer.  I need to look it up by customer ID.  So I am relying on a client side and query solution.

MVCReportViewer: https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer

Comment: Why don't you generate a GUID along with the invoice and use that with the invoice ID to verify that a user should be able to see it. It's very unlikely a user will guess an invoice ID and a random GUID.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx encrypt and decrypt fields in SQL Server

Comment: Why can't you make the user log in and validate the customer ID against the login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this to the creator of MVCReportViewer and he released an update to encrypt paremters in 4.1.  So that solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would setup the SRSS without anonymous access.  Make users login to view their invoices and only allow them to view their reports with access control.  If they change the ID they'll get an access denied error.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249.aspx

You can set it to use custom authentication and have it call on forms authentication in your web app to validate customer access.  Give each customer a forms account via a Membership and Role Privider like the out of the box SQL Server Membership/Role Provider.

Answer (score 1):

The only real way I think of doing this is to establish an asymmetrical key pair, giving the write (or public) key to your C# process, and storing the read (or private) key in the SQL database.

You could then use T-SQL's DECRYPTBYKEY and C#'s CryptoServiceProvider (or similar) to decrypt the key.

If you use a shared secret, the content can be decrypted within your C# process. If that's OK, then stick with AES as it's significantly easier (IMO) to understand.